# Как сделать так чтобы при клике на фоновую картинку не срабатывал скрипт, и значение data оставалось текущим на чистом js?

Tags: javascript, html, counter

Задача была в следующем: при клике на этаж квартиры, элементу добавляется класс, а у счётчика этажей меняется число этажа в зависимости от выбраного. Реализовал через data атрибут, но есть проблема. Сама картинка, по которой производится клик - svg формата, и состоит из фонового изображения и этажей. У этажей есть data атрибут и при клике на них все нормально, но при клике на фоновую картинку, значение счётчика просто пропадает.

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на фоновую картинку значение счётчика не пропадало и было равно выбраному этажу (если выбран 2 этаж - то значение 2 и т.д).
Вот ссылка на проект: https://plupiks.github.io/melody-landing/

```
const houseFloor = document.querySelector('.house-img');
const floorCountNumb = document.querySelector('.hero--value');

// делаю выбранный этаж активным
houseFloor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var floors = document.querySelectorAll(".house-floor");
  var floorActive = e.target;
  Array.from(floors).forEach(i => {
    i.classList.remove("house-img--active");
  })
  floorActive.classList.add("house-img--active");

// присваивание номера этажа
  var floorCount = e.target.dataset.floor;
  floorCountNumb.textContent = floorCount;
  console.log(floorCount);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить проверку. Когда кликаешь не на этаже `e.target.dataset.floor` undefined

```js
houseFloor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var floors = document.querySelectorAll(".house-floor");
  var floorActive = e.target;
  Array.from(floors).forEach(i => {
    i.classList.remove("house-img--active");
  })
  floorActive.classList.add("house-img--active");
  var floorCount = e.target.dataset.floor;
  
  if(floorCount) floorCountNumb.textContent = floorCount;
  console.log(floorCount);
})
```

Comment: Понял спасибо. А вот выделение выбраного этажа пропадает при клике на фоновое изображение, тоже добавить проверку, или там уже по другому?

Comment: Обработчик повесить не на картинку, а на svg `var floors = document.querySelectorAll(".house-floor");
floors.forEach(e=>{
e.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var floorActive = e.target;
  floors.forEach(e => {
    e.classList.remove("house-img--active");
  })
  floorActive.classList.add("house-img--active");
  var floorCount = e.target.dataset.floor;
  if(floorCount) floorCountNumb.textContent = floorCount;
})
})`

Comment: Спасибо) Очень помог

Comment: На здоровье! `if(floorCount)` можно убрать..